# How to make WebDriverIO to wait until react native web fully loaded

Tags: react-native, appium, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

We are planning to automate react native web on mobile web browser using WebDriverIO , appium , in javascript ..but we found couple of challenges like wait for page load, wait for elment visible in case of react native web
i have gone through couple of available answers on stack-overflow but could not help ,so i thought to take help from our experts here

can you please someone help me to get some good solution, here is the source code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI21w.png)

```
**Test Code:**
describe('My Login application', async () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await browser.url('./');
    await browser.setTimeout({'script': 999999999})

  });

  it(’turn pages', async function () {
    document.querySelector("#View")
    const view=$('#View')
    await view.waitForExist(25000)
    const isview=await view.isExisting();
    console.log('isview:'+isview)
    if(isview) {
      await $('.header__wrapper').waitForClickable(9999999)
      await $('.header__wrapper').click()
      await $('.OrderView').waitForDisplayed(999999);
      console.log('order value:' + await 
      $('.OrderView').getHTML());
      console.log('checking title:')
      const title1 = await $('.chapter-title')
      await title1.waitForExist({timeout: 50000});
      console.log('checking html:')
      console.log('html value:' + await title1.getHTML())
      const form = await $('iframe')
      await form.waitForExist()

      console.log('html value:' + form)

      console.log('iframe:' + form)
      await browser.setTimeout({'script': 20000})

      await browser.keys("ArrowLeft")
      await browser.keys("Enter")

      const container = await $('.container');
      await container.waitForExist({timeout: 50000});
      await browser.pause(9999999);
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please put the text of your code in your question, with code formatting (indented).

Comment: Added my code here, please check

Comment: can anyone do help on this ?